# how to use $currentdate in mongodb using C# drivers

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write below query for updating time with the server-side time in C#.

```
db.users.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    {
        $currentDate:
        {
            lastModified: true,
            lastModifiedTS: { $type: "timestamp" }
        }
    })
```

Could anyone please suggest how to run this command through C# code and which driver version do I need to use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost a year later I stumbled upon this question to do the same and did a little research.

I found this interesting way in version 1.9.2 of the official mongo driver:

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", 1);
var update = Update
   .Set("field_timestamp_local", DateTime.Now)
   .CurrentDate("field_timestamp_mongo");
collection.Update(query, update);
```

This code sets 2 fields to a timestamp, the first the local clients timestamp, and the second field to the server time.

Comment: This is not the server time!

Comment: @conceptacid: The first field is local, the second is actually set to server time! I did an edit to make this more clear.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to achieve the same result with an insert (use .CurrentDate on a field when the document is created) ?

Comment: @Alex75, I need this as well but it looks like it's not currently possible unless you do an update with upsert. There is an open Jira ticket to address that:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13695

Answer (score 3):

Since `$currentDate` is a new feature of the upcoming 2.6 version, it might not be supported by your current driver. You could always use BSON documents instead of the strongly-typed wrappers to execute it:

```
collection.Update(
  new QueryDocument() { { "_id", 1 } }, 
  new UpdateDocument() { 
    { "$currentDate", new BsonDocument {
      { "lastModified", true },
      { "lastModifiedTS", new BsonDocument { { "$type", "timestamp" } } }
    } } 
  });
```

I assume the next version of the C# driver will support a strongly-typed helper for this.

Comment: I have one more question. How can we use $currentDate to get the server side datetime. I don't want to update any field in the collection. I jmust need to get the date time in my code and use it there.   Thanks!!

Comment: There's no easy way to do this AFAIK. You could use `eval` to just ask the server to evaluate `new Date()` for you, but that's not a good idea. Maybe there's a way to force the DB to generate an ObjectID for you, from which you could extract the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Avish! I am able to extract date from ServerStatus command result.

Comment: Depending on how frequently you do this, you can run into performance trouble with using `serverStatus` because it's relatively expensive, I think.